# Convert integer to byte in java

Tags: java

I am looking for a way to convert an integer value (like 22, 32, 42) to the corresponding fake hex value (like 0x22, 0x32, 0x42). 
Can anyone have a solution for this type of problem?

Comment: What do you mean fake hex?

Comment: Do you mean treat decimal digits as though they are hexadecimal?

Comment: Uhh, `"0x" + value` ?

Comment: The true hex value of the integer 22 is 0x16, but I only need to convert that value to 0x22 (like adding 0x before an integer), I called this conversion value as fake hex.

Comment: This looks like [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need converting `22` to `0x22`? Are you trying to calculate its decimal value (`34` here)?

Comment: It's related to my project. I want to transfer some bytes of data to specific hardware and in order to hardware works correctly, I should fulfill this rule of conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the 0x appended:  `"0x"+value`.  If you want to convert the int to the appropriate number for that hex value

```
String temp = Integer.toString(value);
int asHex = Integer.valueOf(temp, 16);
```

Comment: There is no method String.parseInt() !! Did you mean Integer.parseInt()?

Comment: I meant integer.valueOf.  Got my languages confused for a minute

Comment: Does the same as mine, would you really recommend going via a string for this?

Comment: It works. Thanks.
If any person wants to test this solution and see the result in the log window use the Integer.toHexString() method for display.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want this, it seems strange you won't ever output `0xA` through `0xF` (because it can't be in the input) but here it is anyway, I hope it at least helps you spot the probable flaw in your approach:

```
public static int fakeHex(int i) {
    int result = 0;
    int base = 1;
    while (i > 0) {
        int decimalDigit = i % 10;
        result += base * decimalDigit;
        i /= 10;
        base *= 16;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Test cases:

```
@Test
public void fake_hex_test() {
    assertEquals(0x0, fakeHex(0));
    assertEquals(0x9, fakeHex(9));
    assertEquals(0x22, fakeHex(22));
    assertEquals(0x32, fakeHex(32));
    assertEquals(0x42, fakeHex(42));
    assertEquals(0x123, fakeHex(123));
}
```